# i want to connect my modal to my main component such that, anytime a component is changed in the modal, it should have effect on the main component

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, modal-dialog, components

**this is my modal component***

*mod.js*

```
export const Mod = () => {
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
<View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
```

> HERE I HAVE PASSED THE SELECT FUNCTION TO MY ONPRESS

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { select2(); }} style={styles.modalText}>
          <Text> select 2 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => select3()} style={styles.modalText}>
          <Text> select 3 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => select4()} style={styles.modalText}>
          <Text> select 4 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      
        <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>

  <Pressable style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
    onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>CHANGE  {modal}</Text>
    <AntDesign name='arrowright' style={styles.icon} />
  </Pressable>
</View>
);
};
```

**This is my Main component**

*Main.js*

```
 const Main = () => {
```

> in this input, i want to be able to select some numbers

```
const [input, setInput] = useState(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]);
const [num, setNum] = useState([]);
```

**these are functions i wants to pass separately to the modal**

```
const select2 = (text) => setNum(oldText => {
  if (oldText.length <= 2) {
    return [...oldText, text]
  }
  else return oldText
})

const select3 = (text) => setNum(oldText => {
  if (oldText.length <= 3) {
    return [...oldText, text]
  }
  else return oldText
})
const select8 = (text) => setNum(oldText => {
  if (oldText.length <= 8) {
    return [...oldText, text]
  }
  else return oldText
})

return (
  <View>
    <Mod />
    <View style={styles.item}>
      {
        input.map((m, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{color:"#fff"}}>{m}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }
        )}
      <View><Text>{num}</Text></View>
    </View>
  </View>
)
```

}

```
**The problem is, i have passed the function select2 from the Main component to the modal but is not working. **
```

**i want the modal component to be able to control the main component with the select functions**